# Can't run or import JARs with Java 10 and Java 11

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, java-10, java-11

I am unable to run `.jar` archives using Java 10 or Java 11 (they exit with `NoClassDefFoundError`). Likewise, I am also unable to import `.jar` archives into a Java Project; they appear in the Classpath, but Eclipse says that the import cannot be resolved. When I downgraded to Java 8, I was able to run `.jar` archives just fine and they would also be recognized in any Java Project that imported them.

For example:

I am importing `mongo-java-driver-3.8.2` into a Java Project on Eclipse Photon. I add the `.jar` to the Project's Classpath (Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path). However, Eclipse outputs `The import com.mongodb cannot be resolved`, as seen in the picture below:

[image]

Comment: You've got to understand the fact that classpath is not alone now, its accompanied by something called modulepath and that your `jars` have to be present in either of these. Sounds like from your setup ideally Eclipse should be taking care of that, which in few other questions seems to be working fine. That said, please check the compatibility of the version of Eclipse you're using and the jar(libraries) you're using further with Java10/11.

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Comment: I would guess that you see effects of modulepath vs. classpath. But your question reads like a guy calling his garage "my car is making strange noises. now tell me how to fix that". We can't, given the amount of information we got so far.

Comment: Do you use JPMS (does the default package contain a `module-info.java` file)?

Comment: It does contain that file.
@GhostCat Sorry. I have edited my original question to include an example.

Comment: Does removing `module-info.java` fix your issue? Or adding the line `requires mongo.java.driver;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the default package contains a `module-info.java` file, you are using the Java Platform Module System (JPMS) and you have two options:

- **Delete `module-info.java`** to not use JPMS and to use the **classpath** as in Java 8
- In `module-info.java` add the line **`requires mongo.java.driver;`** to add the module `mongo.java.driver` (which exports the package `com.mongodb`) to the **modulepath** (since Java 9 you can use either the classpath without a `module-info.java` file or the modulepath with the `module-info.java` file)